# Append a jQuery element to a string that contains html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery wrapped element which I would like to append to a html row. I can't wrap my head around this, since append() seemingly accepts strings but not existing jQuery elements (I might be mistaken here).
I have a following setup:

```
var row='<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>';
var img=$('<img src="path/to/img.png"');
img.click(myClickHandler);
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to append this img element to my row and 'close' the row with a closing  tag.
I'm doing it as follows:

```
var jRow=$(row);
jRow.append(img);
jRow.append('</td></tr>');
```

After my row is ready I append it to my table:

```
$('#tableId').append(jRow);
```

Well, all above doesn't work, because I get [Object Object] instead of image tag in my added row.

My goal is to have a row with an image in last cell and a working click handler.

Pleease, help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a string to **`append()`** it is first "converted" to a DOM element/collection. So, every single string you pass to **`append()`** must be valid HTML/XHTML; you can't add bits of string on later. The image can still be appended to the table row even if you close the tags beforehand. E.g.

```
var row='<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td></td></tr>';
var img=$('<img src="path/to/img.png"/>');
img.click(myClickHandler);

var jRow = $(row);
$('td:last', jRow).append(img);
```

---

When you pass anything to **`append()`** or **`html()`** or **`prepend()`** (or any other similar method) try to forget about strings; what you just passed is no longer a string; it has been parsed as HTML and has been added to the document as a DOM element (or a number of DOM elements).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think HTML fragments should always be "complete", meaning that adding just `"</td></tr>"` will not work.

A solution would be to build a string with a complete HTML fragment, and then append it, instead of appending the pieces one at a time. You can always add the click handler after you created your jQuery object, like this:

```
jRow.find("img").click(function () { ... });
```

Comment: I would guess he already has a table he's just manipulating rows in. But besides that, I absolutely agree :)

Answer (score -2):

How about trying with `jRow.html()`, like this?

```
$('#tableId').append(jRow.html());
```

It should return you the actual HTML contents instead of the jQuery-wrapped element (jQuery object), which is probably what causes the problem, since append() expects to get a String to append.

- [Attributes/html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html)
- [Manipulation/append()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append)

Comment: That html() call will only return what's contained within the <tr> - it won't return the actual <tr> itself. Also, this won't solve the main problem.

Comment: html() and append() or almost exactly the same in functionality; have a look at the jQuery source. And append() can accept strings, DOM elements, jQuery objects, pretty much anything...